# Amazon ads api crashing my app?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, amazon-web-services

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class android.os.Environment
    at com.amazon.device.ads.DebugProperties.readDebugProperties(DebugProperties.java:75)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.InternalAdRegistration.<init>(InternalAdRegistration.java:52)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.InternalAdRegistration.getInstance(InternalAdRegistration.java:64)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initialize(AdLayout.java:185)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.initialize(AdLayout.java:176)
    at com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout.<init>(AdLayout.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
```

My main.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:Amazon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.amazon.device.ads"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="top|center_horizontal" >

<com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout  
android:id="@+id/myAdView" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

My MainActivity.java is this

```
import com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout;
import com.amazon.device.ads.AdRegistration;
import com.amazon.device.ads.AdTargetingOptions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int defaultValue = R.drawable.blue;
    int themedefault = ThemeChanger.THEME_BLUE;
    appliedtheme = preferences.getInt("mytheme", themedefault);
    ThemeChanger.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this, appliedtheme);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AdRegistration.setAppKey("Application_Key");
    this.adView = (AdLayout) findViewById(R.id.myAdView);
    this.adView.loadAd(new AdTargetingOptions());

    button1 = preferences.getInt("DigitButtonStyle", defaultValue);
    buttonmadd = preferences.getInt("MemoryButtonStyle", defaultValue);
    buttoncos = preferences.getInt("FunctionButtonStyle", defaultValue);
```

Comment: Did you manage to get through this issue ? If yes can you please share it ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and followed Amazon developer guide. To solve this issue, just copy amazon library and paste it in your libs folder and than run.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in Eclipse ADT plugin, even if you use View.isInEditMode(), in some cases, it crashes in recent API versions (higher than 18). It's fixed in Android Studio.

If you want to see Layout Preview, you can try with different API version lower than 19.

Check the screenshot. It's using API 18. (Red box is Amazon AdLayout)

[image]